# Unix moving/removing files from subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell

if there are several subdirectories in the current working directory, i would like to move only specific filetypes or possibly all the contents of those directories, to the working directory. and then; "rmdir *" those empty directories or "rm -r" those directories (if not empty)

Shouldn't this be done with the "find" utility then pipe | the output to "mv ." (move find results to working directory)? If so what are the find options that i need to pass for example, or What sort of commands should be used to rm or mv files in the subdirectories, and maybe remove the directories afterward?

Is this method safe for moving duplicate filenames in the same directory? or would the files be overwritten, if there are many index.htmls for instance

This should be a basic task in unix, mv or rm specified filetypes from several subdirectories

Answer (score 3):

The following moves all HTML files out of `foo`, and removes empty directories:

```
$ find foo -name '*.html' -type f -exec mv -nv "{}" '.' \;
foo/bar/1.html -> ./1.html
./1.html not overwritten
foo/baz/qux/3.html -> ./3.html
foo/baz/qux/5.html -> ./5.html
$ find foo -depth -type d -delete
```

What's left is HTML files with conflicting file names, files that aren't HTML files, and non-empty folders.

To automatically rename files to prevent duplicate file names, you can use `mktemp`. The syntax is different between operating systems, and the below works on OS X and presumably the BSDs:

```
find foo -name '*.html' -type f -exec bash -c 'mv -v "$0" "./$( mktemp "$( basename "$0" ).XXX" )"' '{}' \;
foo/bar/1.html -> ./1.html.yNr
foo/baz/1.html -> ./1.html.RUu
foo/baz/qux/3.html -> ./3.html.rzu
foo/baz/qux/5.html -> ./5.html.JyW
```

For every HTML file it finds, it launches bash and has it execute the command after `-c`, which is really just an `mv` with a dynamically created (using `mktemp`) destination file name in the current directory.

To make sure it will work as intended, you can `echo` the `mv` command first as a preview:

```
find foo -name '*.html' -type f -exec bash -c 'echo mv -v "$0" "./$( mktemp "$( basename "$0" ).XXX" )"' '{}' \;
mv -v foo/bar/1.html ./1.html.VNf
mv -v foo/baz/1.html ./1.html.pCW
mv -v foo/baz/qux/3.html ./3.html.ADN
mv -v foo/baz/qux/5.html ./5.html.K3w
```

As you can see, every invocation results in a different suffix thanks to `mktemp` in the `bash` script (you cannot just include that part in a regular `-exec mv` as it'd get evaluated once for the `find` call, and then use the same suffix for all moved).

Depending on the number of files involved, you might need a larger random suffix than just `.XXX`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one go with a command like:\

```
find . -name '*.goaway' -exec mv '{}' destination \;
```

but a safer way may be to to start by just seeing what the find command digs up for you, possibly piping it to a file which you can use for doing the acutal operations.

And yes, if you move all your index.html to the same directory they will clobber each other and you'll only have the last one moved left after.